# android.hardware.camera2.impl.CameraCaptureSessionImpl.finalize() timed out

Tags: android, android-camera2, timeoutexception

The crash log below was reported in the video chat screen implemented using camera2 and agora library.

```
Fatal Exception: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: android.hardware.camera2.impl.CameraCaptureSessionImpl.finalize() timed out after 10 seconds
       at android.hardware.camera2.impl.CameraCaptureSessionImpl.close(CameraCaptureSessionImpl.java:373)
       at android.hardware.camera2.impl.CameraCaptureSessionImpl.finalize(CameraCaptureSessionImpl.java:663)
       at java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerDaemon.doFinalize(Daemons.java:250)
       at java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerDaemon.runInternal(Daemons.java:237)
       at java.lang.Daemons$Daemon.run(Daemons.java:103)
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:780)
```

It was reported to crashlytics of firebase, and it is difficult to confirm the problem because it cannot be reproduced.

Judging from the reported cases so far, it seems that it is only occurring in android 8.1.0.

Both camera2 and agora were written according to their respective development guides.
It is difficult to describe the code for all the implemented parts here. If anyone has experienced the same error as me, can you tell me how you solved it?

Or, can anyone give me advice on how to approach this error?